# Is $\mathbb{Z}_4 \simeq U(5)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am doing a tutorial question where it ask whether or not the groups of order 4 $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+\mod 4)$ and $(U(5),\times _5)$ are isomorphic to each other.

I drew out the Cayley tables and got

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
0&0&1&2&3\\
1&1&2&3&0\\
2&2&3&0&1\\
3&3&0&1&2
\end{array} \qquad \qquad \qquad 
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1&1&2&3&4\\
2&2&4&1&3\\
3&3&1&4&2\\
4&4&3&2&1
\end{array}
$$

The answers said that they are isomorphic because they are both cyclic.

But looking at the Cayley tables I don't think you can define a bijection between elements of the groups (the diagonals do not match).

Can I get clarification on which interpretation is correct?

Comment: The function $\phi: \mathbb Z_4 \to U(5)$ which takes $0 \to 1, 1 \to 2, 2 \to 4, 3 \to 3$ seems like a decent candidate.

Comment: They are isomorphic. Remember that on a bijection you have to _rearrange_ the rows and columns. Try putting the $U(5)$ cayley table in the order $1 \ 2 \ 4 \ 3$ instead of $1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4$. Do the tables match now? How might I have known that this order would work? Is there a way you can figure out the correct order yourself in future problems? What does this have to do with the concept of an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

See that $U(n)$ is the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ under multiplication modulo $n,$ i.e., $U(n)=(\mathbb{Z}_n^*,\times_n).$

We have a result regarding the cyclicity of $U(n),$ in the following article by David R. Guichard, “When Is $U(n)$ Cyclic? An Algebraic Approach,”
Mathematics Magazine 72 (1999): 139–142.

> $U(n)$ is cyclic if and only if $n$ is $1,$ $2,$ $4,$ $p^k,$ or $2p^k,$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

The answer to your question is a direct consequence of this result and the fact that there is only one cyclic group, upto isomorphism, of a given order.

Answer (score 0):

> But looking at the Cayley tables I don't think you can define a bijection between elements of the groups (the diagonals do not match).

Just interchange the second table elements 3 and 4 [The row order in Cayley table is immaterial but you should keep same order in the column]  $$. 
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&\color{red}0&\color{blue}1&\color{orange}2&3\\
\hline
\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{blue}1&\color{orange}2&3\\
\color{blue}1&\color{blue}1&\color{orange}2&3&\color{red}0\\
\color{orange}2&\color{orange}2&3&\color{red}0&\color{blue}1\\
3&3&\color{red}0&\color{blue}1&\color{orange}2
\end{array} \qquad \qquad \qquad 
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}4&3\\
\hline
\color{red}1&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}4&3\\
\color{blue}2&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}4&3&\color{red}1\\
\color{orange}4&\color{orange}4&3&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2\\
3&3&\color{red}1&\color{blue}2&\color{orange}4
\end{array}
$$

Now look at the table and finish what you want..!

Answer (score 0):

You wanted all of them to map in an order... which is not necessary...

Look at the map $f:\mathbb{Z_4}\to U_5$, such that $f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=4, f(3)=3$ it is a bijection, and by watching the Cayley table itself you can conclude that this is an Isomorphism

Answer (score 0):

Use the first Cayley table to "iteratively" compute:
$$1, \space1+1, \space(1+1)+1, \space[(1+1)+1]+1$$
Same with the second to compute:
$$2,\space 2.2,\space (2.2).2, \space [(2.2).2].2$$
You'll find out that no entries in the two sequences are groups' identities but the last ones. What does it mean?